# Page value is only available after content dimensions are established

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Slideshow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: true,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          viewportFraction: .75,
        ),
        items: [
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/san-67ce2.appspot.com/o/clothes.jpeg?alt=media&token=d3be6bcb-4a40-4c78-a577-0b4f6a386536",
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/san-67ce2.appspot.com/o/clothes.jpeg?alt=media&token=d3be6bcb-4a40-4c78-a577-0b4f6a386536",
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/san-67ce2.appspot.com/o/clothes.jpeg?alt=media&token=d3be6bcb-4a40-4c78-a577-0b4f6a386536",
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/san-67ce2.appspot.com/o/clothes.jpeg?alt=media&token=d3be6bcb-4a40-4c78-a577-0b4f6a386536",
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/san-67ce2.appspot.com/o/clothes.jpeg?alt=media&token=d3be6bcb-4a40-4c78-a577-0b4f6a386536",
        ].map((i) {
          return Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                    child: Image.network(
                      i,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                    )),
              );
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm writing flutter code by using carousel slider package (package creates beautiful slideshow), this exception is being thrown every time I run the code, I couldn't understand why.

**_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 373 pos 7: 'pixels == null || (minScrollExtent != null && maxScrollExtent != null)': Page value is only available after content dimensions are established.)**

Answer (score -1):

Creates a MaterialApp.

At least one of [home], [routes], [onGenerateRoute], or [builder] must be
non-null.
https://blog.csdn.net/u013491829/article/details/108921275

Comment: I do have material app with home, and this slideshow is viewed in certain case,